# Get correct Pandas version in IPython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In an IPython notebook, when I `print pd.__name__, pd.__version__` the result is:

```
pandas 0.14.1
```

I only have one environment, the root environment, and when I:

```
!conda list -n root
```

I am told that pandas is 0.16.1.
Why is it that these are different?  How can I update my pandas version in the notebook?

I have tried `pip install` and `conda update` and both tell me that I am using the latest version of pandas.

**UPDATE:**

I am launching the notebook using the Anaconda desktop Launcher and when I run `import IPython; IPython.__path__` the result is:

/Users/charlie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython

Comment: How are you launching the notebook?

Comment: Can you show the output of `import IPython; IPython.__path__` in the notebook?

Comment: Make sure you have `ipython` installed in same environment (`root`).

Comment: And what does `pd.__path__` show? Does it come from the same site-packages directory?

Comment: pd.__path__ shows - /Users/charlie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas

Comment: When u execute that conda list -n root, what is that path that prints on the first line?

Comment: When I execute conda list -n root I get -/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

Comment: You should be getting  # packages in environment at /Users/charlie/anaconda:

Comment: The complete return is # packages in environment at /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7:   Followed by a list of packages and package numbers.  So how can I navigate into Users/charlie/anaconda?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not much help on this one.  I'm baffled.  Maybe ask a new question with this new information and use the anaconda tag

Comment: try: cd /Users/charlie/anaconda